# JQuery UI Drag/Droppable with multiple scopes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to have several classes of draggables, each one corresponding to a class of droppables. But in addition, I want to have a separate "waste bin", where all the draggables can be dropped until a suitable droppable can be found for them.

Now, this can be easily achieved with an accept function. However, I may have up to 20 classes, each one with 30-40 draggables/droppables. So if I use an "accept" function for this, the moment I pick up a draggable, my chrome freezes as it runs tests for every droppable on the screen :(

This can be solved if I use the 'scope' property, since it seems to be using some different way. However, when I use a scope, I can't seem to implement the "waste bin" concept, since it can only have one scope!

Is there some way to by-pass this problem? Give the draggables more than one scope, or giving the waste bin many scopes? Or maybe some other solution I can't think of?

Comment: hi.  can you post some code so we can see what you have so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internally jQuery UI will run the following code whenever you start dragging a `draggable` to determine which `droppable`s are eligible to receive the `draggable`.

```
var m = $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[t.options.scope] || [];
var type = event ? event.type : null; // workaround for #2317
var list = (t.currentItem || t.element).find(":data(droppable)").andSelf();

droppablesLoop: for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

    if(m[i].options.disabled || (t && !m[i].accept.call(m[i].element[0],(t.currentItem || t.element)))) continue;   //No disabled and non-accepted
    for (var j=0; j < list.length; j++) { if(list[j] == m[i].element[0]) { m[i].proportions.height = 0; continue droppablesLoop; } }; //Filter out elements in the current dragged item
    m[i].visible = m[i].element.css("display") != "none"; if(!m[i].visible) continue;                                   //If the element is not visible, continue

    if(type == "mousedown") m[i]._activate.call(m[i], event); //Activate the droppable if used directly from draggables

    m[i].offset = m[i].element.offset();
    m[i].proportions = { width: m[i].element[0].offsetWidth, height: m[i].element[0].offsetHeight };

}
```

As you can see the code is non trivial and would explain why you're seeing slow performance every time you start dragging.

One thing to note is that the very first thing checked in the `droppablesLoop` is whether the `droppable` is disabled.

Therefore, to increase performance you could always manually disable the appropriate `droppable` widgets which will make you quickly jump out of the code block above.  You can do this by using the `start` event on the `draggable`, which will fire first.

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    start: function() {
        $('.invalid-droppable-elements').droppable('option', 'disabled', true);
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('.invalid-droppable-elements').droppable('option', 'disabled', false);
    }
});
```

This essentially makes you implement the `accept` / `scope` logic yourself and the performance impact is up to your algorithm.  It shouldn't be that bad to implement though.  The reason the plugins are as slow as they are is because they have to handle for a LOT of different situations.

jQuery UI does not support adding multiple scopes to individual `draggable` / `droppable` elements but you could roll that functionality on your own.

I put an example together to show this here - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/TgQTP/1/.

Comment: This actually had a nice effect on performance, but still very slim as opposed to using scope... I actually had all the droppables disabled except the bin and enabled only the ones I need. Is there no way to make something belong to more than one scope?

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question.  The short answer is no jQuery UI doesn't support multiple scopes but it's pretty easy to implement this on your own.

Comment: This is great, but for anyone wondering there does seem to be a little extra "complexity" with the `.each`. Unless I'm missing something you can simply reference `$('.draggable')` and move the assignment of `var scope` to `start`